# How do I get LastPass to remember to use social-media logins on websites?

Tags: website, lastpass

Many websites today let users register and login using Facebook or Google Accounts so users don't need to remmeber a username and password for each website. When logging-in the username and password form is hosted on the `google.com` or `facebook.com` domains.

However LastPass only seems to remember logins for websites when I use a username and password used on their own domain, because the login form isn't hosted by the website on its own domain LastPass doesn't record anything - it doesn't record me clicking the "Register with Google" or "Register with Facebook" links either - so LastPass doesn't record me having anything to do with those websites at all.

How can I get LastPass to remember that I registered for a site with Google or Facebook?

(I'm asking because recently I completely forgot that I signed up for a website using Google and wasted an hour and the website's support team's time by trying to login using their own login form).

Comment: You have to be logged into Google or Facebook which LastPass can remember the password for, but there is nothing for LastPass to manage in your example, if you were logged into Google/Facebook the website would authentication would have been instantaneous.